# Disable 'wrap text output on resize' in console application

Tags: c++, winapi

With the new Windows 10 console, it exists a new property: 'wrap text output on resize'
We find this new checkbox in the window-property-page in the tab "Layout"

I noticed that the display behaviour changes under win32-console-applications depending this property.

For example: With the same console window width (in pixels) the character width (nbr of chars) changes

Is there a C++ function to set this property 'wrap text output on resize' to "disabled" ?

Comment: What negative effect does this setting have on your program?

Comment: I don't get the same amount of chars vertically.
With  'wrap text output on resize' enabled I get with a certain pixel-width 98 chars and with the property disabled an amount of 100 chars vertically.

It's not a real bug, but each user should have the same width.
Because some grids are working on a specific width

To ensure that each user has the same width I resize the console-window to a specific width(in pixel) but the width in characters are not equal